# select xml filename from database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a sql script that loads the filenames of the xml's in a database (tmp1).

the list looks like this:

```
20130918_0932_ZSK40-2.xml
20130918_1032_ZSK70.xml
20130921_0532_ZSK40-2.xml
```

in another script I want to load each xml file so that I can import it in the database.

What I need is to select the first file name in the tmp1 to load it.

The part of the script to load the file is like this:

```
 SELECT CAST(XmlContent AS XML)
    FROM OPENROWSET(
         BULK 'C:\20130921_0532_ZSK40-2.xml',
         SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(XmlContent)
         ) AS T(XmlContent)
```

what should It look like?

Thanks in advance,

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTable') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE #tmpTable

SELECT machine = XmlContent.value('(/recordedData/machine)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
 RecordingDate = XmlContent.value('(/recordedData/date)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
 RecordingTime = XmlContent.value('(/recordedData/hour)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
 VariableName = XVar.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
 VariableValue = XVar.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
Into #tmpTable
FROM (

SELECT CAST(XmlContent AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
 BULK 'C:\xml_path_here.xml',
 SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(XmlContent)
 ) AS T(XmlContent)
CROSS APPLY
 XmlContent.nodes('/recordedData/CollectedData/variable') AS XTbl(XVar)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.VariableName) 
 FROM #tmpTable c
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
 ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT machine, RecordingDate, RecordingTime, ' + @cols + ' from 
 (
 select machine
 , RecordingDate
 , RecordingTime
 , VariableName
 , VariableValue
 from #tmpTable
 ) x
 pivot 
 (
 max(VariableValue)
 for VariableName in (' + @cols + ')
 ) p '


execute(@query)
--SELECT * FROM #tmpTable
drop table #tmpTable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time. Additionally, you appear to be using non-standard SQL features but you don't mention that your database engine is. Please retag the question accordingly.

Comment: Load the contents where? In one table? Each XML file in a different table?

Comment: @user2725348 So, each XML in its table, correct?

Comment: the xml filenames will be different each time. im just trying to insert it one by one, but im having troubles selecting the top1 from the database tmp1 . I assume instead of the path it must some script {select top1 from tmp1} but I don't think this will work

Comment: all xml's will go into one table, but one at a time , will use xp_cmd_shell to delete each file after it is inserted. xml files are generated every 5-10 minutes in a folder.

Comment: @user2725348 Importing in a singleBlob is good for you?

Comment: I see no problem . the way I was thinking to work like this. 
since the xml's are coming continuously
1. create the table with the xml names
2. select the top xml file and insert it with the script above ( it provides me the formatting I need in the database)
3. using xp_cmd_shell , delete the top xml file
4. drop the table with the xml names .

All this inserted into a stored proc, running it with the agent every minute.

Comment: I can also provide a sample xml if you like to help me, and need it.